# Why does (quote(1 2 3)) show '(1 2 3) instead of just (1 2 3)? How do I make the ' go away?

Tags: scheme, racket

Scheme doesn't let me put a list through a function if there is a '.

Comment: Since "put a list through a function" is unclear, please edit your question to be clear, show your code, & best read & act on [mcve].

Comment: The expression `(quote (1 2 3))` simply evaluates to a value, which in this case is a list of 3 numbers, the same thing that `(list 1 2 3)` evaluates to. It does not "show" anything. If you are entering this expression into an REPL, it may try to pretty-print the value that the expression evaluates to in some form that is specific to that REPL, but this is not something that has to do with the language itself.

Comment: Racket prints lists with a leading `'`. You can see examples of this in the [Quick introduction to Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/quick/index.html#%28part._.Lists%29), where it is also explained. Please describe what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Scheme and Racket have different default printing conventions. Use the parameter `print-as-expression` to change the default behavior in Racket.

```
#lang racket
(print-as-expression #f)
(quote (1 2 3))
```

The result will be printed as `(1 2 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

*You have tagged racket. It's unsure if it is because you are programming Scheme (like R5RS or R6RS) in DrRacket or if you are programming `#lang racket` in DrRacket since the tag `racket` can mean both.*

In Racket the REPL displays lists in an unconventional way and it changed depending on the settings you have and the language you are programming in. If you use `#lang racket` the default is not to show you the value but rather an expression that would evaluate to that value.

```
(list 1 2 3) ; ==> '(1 2 3)
```

The real value is `(1 2 3)` since both `(list 1 2 3)` and `'(1 2 3)` evaluates to `(1 2 3)`. It's like answering `2+3` instead of `5` to the question what is `1+4`.  If this is your problem then the `'` isn't really there at all. You can prove that by printing it with `display`:

```
(display (list 1 2 3)) ; ==> (1 2 3)
```

Here i clearly put a list through a function and it shows how that list looks like as a value. If you go and select "Choose language" in the dropdown on the bottom left you can select output style in the modal for `#lang racket`. Here are some previews:

```
(list 1 2 3)
; ==> (list 1 2 3) when using "constructor"
; ==> `(1 2 3) when using quasiquote
; ==> (1 2 3) when using write (same as Scheme and other LISPs)
; ==> '(1 2 3) when using print
```

The other languages supported by Racket this won't change with these settings and it seems R5RS uses constructor and R6RS uses write, but the parentheses are replaced with curlies in R6RS. In both languages only expressions in the interactions window are displayed and not the result of expressions in the definitions window.

I'm unsure if this can be changed, but in the same manner as `#lang racket` this is just visualization so for a function it wouldn't really matter since it doesn't look at a list but rather use it.